# PostgreSQL select from table (without ORDER BY) comes out in different order every time

Tags: postgresql, scan

I have a modestly big table of about a million rows. With static where clauses it filters down to 200,000 rows. With a typical user search criterion it delivers about 100 rows. This is for a web service hit millions of times per hour. I want to keep the database load as small as possible. So cannot afford an order by. But I need to be able to scroll through the result set, with OFFSET / LIMIT clauses. However, for the first time in my life, I notice that for this query the results come out in a different order every single time I run it (on a system with no other activity). I know that there is no guarantee of any particular ordering in SQL, but I am used to the order being at least stable when the criteria don't change and we only use OFFSET and LIMIT.

First I thought it was the parallel query, but even after I turned that off, single threaded table scan

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..316982.62 rows=25 width=471)
  ->  Seq Scan on mytable (cost=0.00..316982.62 rows=25 width=471) 
        Filter: ...
```

I suppose it's a bad idea that I don't use any indexes but only filters. Perhaps that's the anomaly here. But even so, what is the special optimization that PostgreSQL uses that makes it produce a different result all the time? And that seems to be the reason.

But regardless, is there a way I can make sure whatever table scan uses the same whatever random but stable ordering from its table scan?

Comment: Rows in  a table have no implied sort order. The **only** way to have a guaranteed sort order is to use `order by`. There is no alternative - especially if you use OFFSET/LIMIT.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know that, and said so much. The issue is not a guaranteed order but a *usually* stable order so you can do paging with OFFSET and LIMIT.

Comment: If you need to rely on a specific sort order, the **only** way to get that is to use ORDER BY. There is no alternative. There is no such thing as a "usually stable order". If you have observed the same sort order repeatedly, then that was pure coincidence.

Comment: Have you been updating this table over the different times you performed your query?

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні no, subsequent selects immediately following each other with no other activity on the database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are repeating yourself and I made it clear in my original query that I don't care about any specific order. Only that the order doesn't change willy nilly in subsequent queries.

Comment: Well, I repeat myself because you don't accept that the **only** way to get what you want is to use an `ORDER BY`.  There is absolutely no guarantee whatsoever for the database to return the rows in any deterministic order without that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that should be an answer. The only answer to this kind of question.

Comment: Good heavens @a_horse_with_no_name where did I say I want  a "consistent" or "deterministic" order? It's complete nonsense. The synchronize_seqscans might be the reason, so if I have thousands of people paging though this table (in no particular order!!!) then running an order by for all of them each and every time they want to fetch a new page would be insane, wouldn't it? In that case it would make more sense for me to turn off the synchronize_seqscans trick rather than run order by all the time.

Comment: You wrote "*Only that the order doesn't change*" which means a consistent (repeatable, deterministic, always the same) sort order.

Comment: How many rounds need we go through this? What nonsense! I explained exactly what the observation is, and what the requirement for paging is is *stable* order, not "deterministic" nor even "always the same" order. Just reasonably stable so that barring changes to the underlying table things would come out the same way in the duration of a few minutes. Paging has always worked this way, and here it did not. Instead of looking at the practical issues we have to have this ridiculous schooling about stuff everybody knows. You do an ORDER BY a million row table a million times an hour, be my guest.

Comment: Please define what you mean with "stable order"

Comment: I define "stable order" that the same order comes out when running the same query multiple times when none of the underlying tables have been changed.

Comment: This is a really strange behavior, this is the first time I see this kind of things.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68653579/postgresql-returns-random-rows-when-using-large-offset

Answer (score 3):

Why it does it is probably due to [synchronize_seqscans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-SYNCHRONIZE-SEQSCANS).  Now go have fun shooting yourself in the feet with even more vigor.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about synchronize_seqscans, I will check that out. What the point of all that nastiness is, I don't know.

Comment: It seems right, with `set synchronize_seqscans=off`, the order doesn't change anymore.  I had this behavior with `select a, b from table limit bignum (ex 50000)`. We cannot see it in dbeaver because dbeaver adds an implicit limit on each query, we must use `psql` or python to reproduce it

Answer (score 1):

No, the answer is a definite NO.

There is only one way to ensure consistent and repeated order. Using `ORDER BY`.